# Sort np array based on summed selected values of each row

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a 2D numpy array, filled with floats.
I want to take a selected chunk of each row (say item 2nd to 3rd), sum these values and sort all the rows based on that sum in a descending order.

For example:

```
array([[0.80372444, 0.35468653, 0.9081662 , 0.69995566],
       [0.53712474, 0.90619077, 0.69068265, 0.73794143],
       [0.14056974, 0.34685164, 0.87505744, 0.56927803]])
```

Here's what I tried:

```
a = np.array(sorted(a, key = sum))
```

But that just sums all values from each row, rather that, say, only 2nd to 6th element.

Comment: Write & use a function to replace `sum` with the specific calculation you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by using `take` to get elements at indices `[1,2]` from each row (axis = 1).  Then `sum` across those element for each row (again axis = 1), and use `argsort` to get the order of the sums.  This gives a set of row indices, which you can use to slice the array in the desired order.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.80372444, 0.35468653, 0.9081662 , 0.69995566],
              [0.53712474, 0.90619077, 0.69068265, 0.73794143],
              [0.14056974, 0.34685164, 0.87505744, 0.56927803]])

a[a.take([1, 2], axis=1).sum(axis=1).argsort()]
# returns:
array([[0.14056974, 0.34685164, 0.87505744, 0.56927803],
       [0.80372444, 0.35468653, 0.9081662 , 0.69995566],
       [0.53712474, 0.90619077, 0.69068265, 0.73794143]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `key` with the function you actually want:

```
a = np.array(sorted(d, key = lambda v : sum(v[1:3])))
```